# DataRow.GetChanges() or equivalent

Tags: .net, dataset

Using `DataTable.GetChanges()` gives me the list of all rows that are modified. Is there some built-in method to do the same at row level; to check which columns have been modified, other than manually comparing the `ItemArray` in a loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

You could use this code to compare the values with their previous version:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    private static bool hasCellChanged(DataRow row, DataColumn col)
    {
        if (!row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original))
        {
            // Row has been added. All columns have changed. 
            return true;
        }
        if (!row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Current))
        {
            // Row has been removed. No columns have changed.
            return false;
        }
        var originalVersion = row[col, DataRowVersion.Original];
        var currentVersion = row[col, DataRowVersion.Current];
        if (originalVersion == DBNull.Value && currentVersion == DBNull.Value)  
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (originalVersion != DBNull.Value && currentVersion != DBNull.Value)  
        {  
            return !originalVersion.Equals(currentVersion);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataRow row)
    {
        return row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Where(col => hasCellChanged(row, col));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
    {
        return rows.SelectMany(row => row.GetChangedColumns())
            .Distinct();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataTable table)
    {
        return table.GetChanges().Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .GetChangedColumns();
    }
}
```

Adapted from [Verify which columns have changed in a datatable or datarow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/verify-which-columns-have-changed-in-a-datatable-or-datarow).

**Example:**

```
DataTable table;
table.GetChangedColumns()

List<DataRow> listOfRows;
listOfRows.GetChangedColumns()

DataRow row;
row.GetChangedColumns()
```

Comment: You may need to use "return row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(col => hasCellChanged(row, col));" instead in your "IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetChangedColumns(this DataRow row)" function

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: I think the logic of the `hasCellChanged` is wrong. It should be the inverse of the current code (if `originalVersion == DBNull.Value && currentVersion == DBNull.Value` it hasn't changed, but returns true). Edited accordingly.

Comment: I used this code in my project and it have worked fine, however one day our QA found defect when this code throw `VersionNotFoundException `. This occurs when `DataRow` object just added in `DataTable` and `RowState == DataRowState.Added`. I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0.aspx) that `DataRowVersion.Original` version doesn't exist for those rows. Workaround is very simple: `if(row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original)){...}`. For rows where  `RowState == DataRowState.Deleted` the `DataRowVersion.Current` doesn't exist too.

Comment: @Alezis I added a check for the existence of each version. I assumed deleting a row does not count as a column change, and adding a row count as all columns have changed. Ideally you would have already filtered out added and deleted rows before calling these methods.